# multiple echo output in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I am new to scripting. I want to incorporate number of lines getting output of echo into one line :

```
   echo "$reasult1 \n"
   echo "$reasult2 \n"
   echo "$reasult3 \n"
   echo "$reasult4 \n"
   echo "$reasult5 \n"
   echo "$reasult6 \n"
   echo "$reasult7 \n"
   echo "$reasult8 \n"
   echo "$reasult9 \n"
   echo "$reasult10 \n"
```

I want one line for the above .

Comment: `echo $reasult{1..10}`

Comment: Con you clarify your question? I don't understand what you want to be one line only.

Answer (score 1):

The way `echo` works varies a bit from shell to shell. You can use `printf` instead, which is a little more uniform.

```
# printf does not print a newline by default. If you really want two newlines per
# echo, as implied by your code, add another \n to the format string.
printf "%s\n" "$result1" "$result2" "$result3"
```

with however many variables you want. The format in the first argument is repeated as many times as necessary to consume all the remaining arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $reasult1 $reasult2 $reasult3 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e 'Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n and so on ...\n'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.